# Add some information in additional_options of quote_item_option table while adding item to quote while creating order from backend

Tags: magento2, backend, quote

I want to add some information in additional_options of quote_item_option table while adding item to quote while creating order from backend. For this purpose I need an event that called after adding item in quote from backend.

FYI it is saving in info_buyRequest right now.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller file, put this data, make changes according to your needs and code.

path : **vendor/addtocart/controller/index/index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Addtocart\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $formKey;   
    protected $cart;
    protected $product;
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_session;
    protected $serializer;
    protected $ProductRepository;

    protected $_responseFactory;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $ProductRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session,
    \Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface $serializer,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $PageFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    array $data = []) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;

        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->_pageFactory = $PageFactory;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
        $this->product = $product; 
        $this->ProductRepository = $ProductRepository;
        $this->_session = $session;    
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
      $page = $this->_pageFactory->create();
      $productId =1;
      $id = $this->_session->getId();
      $additionalOptions['firstnamesku'] = [
                'label' => 'First Name',
                'value' => 'chirag',
            ];
      $additionalOptions['lnamesku'] = [
                'label' => 'Last Name',
                'value' => 'parmar',
            ];
      $additionalOptions['emailidsku'] = [
                'label' => 'Email ID',
                'value' => 'chirag@gmail.com',
            ];
      $additionalOptions['phonenosku'] = [
                'label' => 'Phone No',
                'value' => '1234567890',
            ];

      if(!$this->_session->isLoggedIn()){
      $params = array(
                    'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                    'product' => $productId, //product Id
                    'qty'   =>1 //quantity of product
            );   
       }else{
            $params = array(
                    'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                    'product' => $productId, //product Id
                    'qty'   =>1, //quantity of product
                    'customer_id'   =>$id
            );
    }           
    //Load the product based on productID   
    $_product = $this->ProductRepository->getById($productId);
    $_product->addCustomOption('additional_options', $this->serializer->serialize($additionalOptions)); 
    $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
    $this->cart->save();
    //return $page;
    $message = "Product have been successfully added to your Shopping Cart.";
    $this->messageManager->addSuccess($message);
    $accUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart/');
    $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($accUrl)->sendResponse();
    $this->setRefererUrl($accUrl);
  }
}
?>
```

This will save your data to tables like **sales_order_item**, **quote_item_option**, and related tables.